# Grab and compare custom list from div inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, list

```
<div class="m_data_list" id="a1">
    <div class="m_data a_rcnm5" id="a_uk54q" 
        onclick="xlist(1, 20, 'rnamx', 'rcnm5', 'uk54q', '', 'uk54q', true)">Kowalski</div>
    <div class="m_data a_rcnm5" id="a_mcrgn" 
        onclick="xlist(1, 20, 'rnamx', 'rcnm5', 'mcrgn', '', 'uk54q', true)">Melman</div>
    <div class="m_data a_rcnm5" id="a_w26tp" 
        onclick="xlist(1, 20, 'rnamx', 'rcnm5', 'w26tp', '', 'uk54q', true)">Marty</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="m_data_list" style="" id="a2">
    <div class="m_data a_n0ql8" id="a_u4tes" 
        onclick="xlist(2, 15, 'vghwa', 'n0ql8', 'u4tes', '', 'u4tes', true)">FALSE</div>
    <div class="m_data a_n0ql8" id="a_p8ixf" 
        onclick="xlist(2, 15, 'vghwa', 'n0ql8', 'p8ixf', '', 'u4tes', true)">TRUE</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Here's a snippet of code of `a1`, there are many of similar div's like `a1`.
I actually want to **compare all** **xlist** in context of a1, a2.
In one xlist in each a1, a2 .., two elements are same, like below *(see `uk54q`)*

```
<div class="m_data a_rcnm5" id="a_uk54q" 
    onclick="xlist(1, 20, 'rnamx', 'rcnm5', 'uk54q', '', 'uk54q', true)">Kowalski</div>
```

There are many options, I want to select which has same elements in xlist.

I am new to JS and researched for hours and came this far.

```
$.each($('div.m_data'), function(a, b) {
    console.log($(this).attr('onclick'))
});
```

It extracts all `xlists` from a1 to a15

```
$.each($('div.m_data'), function(a, b) {
    console.log(b.innerHTML)
})
```

It displays all the options. ie. *(Kowalski, Melman, Marty)*

I tried to trim from xlist and was unable to do so, and tried many things that didn't worked out.

Comment: I don't see class `m_question_q` anywhere in your markup. also where is `xlist` function?

Comment: I am so sorry, I made a typo, corrected it.
For `xlist`, see the `onclick` in div.

Comment: Just a note, your `console.log`s are missing semicolons at the end.

Comment: I checked, it worked without the `;`. And I included and it gave the same result. Please try doing without `;` and tell me did that worked?

Comment: so, what you need is the `div`s with `onclick` attribute pointing to a function which has at least one argument repeated? in your snippet for example, the result would be `[a_uk54q, a_u4tes]`? if that's not, please explain yourself a little better

Comment: like there are many `onclick` having xlist, right?
I want to compare each xlist with it's elements, and if any two same elements exists, bingo!

Comment: @scaramouche : I mean, let's see, `<div class="m_data_list" id="a1">`
I want to get "Kowalski" as it's xlist has `uk54q` two times.
This is the case with each main div, every sub div having various xlists has some xlist having same two elements :)

Answer (score 0):

In case you have not cracked this one yet, you can get each function declaration as a string, then with some simple regex get the arguments as an array. From then on it's just about finding more efficient ways to find duplicates in them, if performance is a must I recommend changing the bubblesort-like one I provided.

```js
function containsDuplicates(arr){
  var temp = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++){
    for(var j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++){
      if(arr[i] === arr[j]){
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  
  return false;
}

var results = {};
$('div.m_data_list').each(function(i){
  var $this = $(this);
  var $thisID = $this.attr('id');
  results[$thisID] = [];
  
  $(this).children('div.m_data').each(function(j){
    var funcString = $(this).attr('onclick');
    
    var ini = funcString.indexOf("(");
    var arr = funcString.substr(
        ini+1,
        funcString.indexOf(")") - ini - 1)
        .replace(/ /g,"").split(',');

    if(containsDuplicates(arr)){
      results[$thisID].push($(this).text());
    }
    
  });
});

console.log(results);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="m_data_list" id="a1">
    <div class="m_data a_rcnm5" id="a_uk54q" 
        onclick="xlist(1, 20, 'rnamx', 'rcnm5', 'uk54q', '', 'uk54q', true)">Kowalski</div>
    <div class="m_data a_rcnm5" id="a_mcrgn" 
        onclick="xlist(1, 20, 'rnamx', 'rcnm5', 'mcrgn', '', 'uk54q', true)">Melman</div>
    <div class="m_data a_rcnm5" id="a_w26tp" 
        onclick="xlist(1, 20, 'rnamx', 'rcnm5', 'w26tp', '', 'uk54q', true)">Marty</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="m_data_list" style="" id="a2">
    <div class="m_data a_n0ql8" id="a_u4tes" 
        onclick="xlist(2, 15, 'vghwa', 'n0ql8', 'u4tes', '', 'u4tes', true)">FALSE</div>
    <div class="m_data a_n0ql8" id="a_p8ixf" 
        onclick="xlist(2, 15, 'vghwa', 'n0ql8', 'p8ixf', '', 'u4tes', true)">TRUE</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```